# ZF2 Hydrator and LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am hydrating a MySQL result:

```
public function getMiscdamage($id) 
{
    $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
    $select = $sql->select('misc_damage');
    $select->where(array('vehicle_id = ?' => $id))->order('date_added DESC');
    $select->join('user','user.user_id = misc_damage.added_user_id', array('added_user_display_name' => 'display_name'), 'left');

    $stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult()) {
        $resultSet = new HydratingResultSet(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods(), new \Application\Model\Miscdamage());

        return $resultSet->initialize($result);
    }

    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Vehicle with given ID:{$id} not found.");
}
```

The query has a LEFT join, and the query DOES work. But when I `var_dump` in a loop through, the added_user_display_name` is null:

```
/var/www/zf-skeleton/module/Application/view/application/live/details.phtml:337:
object(Application\Model\Miscdamage)[662]
  protected 'id' => string '100' (length=3)
  protected 'vehicle_id' => string '8' (length=1)
  protected 'added_user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  protected 'added_user_display_name' => null
  protected 'description' => string 'dfgdggfdd' (length=9)
  protected 'date_added' => string '2016-04-15 12:26:40' (length=19)
  protected 'date_repaired' => null
  protected 'repaired_user_id' => null
  protected 'status' => string '0' (length=1)
```

How do I go about using a left join and hydrator? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You sql result is a response from a functionnal need of data. Therefore, you should use a custom hydrator built specifically for this functionnal need. This hydrator is often an aggregator hydrator which uses multiple hydrator to build a custom model. You should check it out

Comment: Thanks :) Add that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql result is a response from a functionnal need of data. Therefore, you should use a custom hydrator built specifically for this functionnal need. This hydrator is often an aggregator hydrator which uses multiple hydrator to build a custom model. You should check it out